# How do I stop vim from higlighting uncessary words in PHP

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-php

I have this issue with my vim setup, where some words get highlighted unnecessarily. The image below shows an example. The words *not* and *to* where highlighted but there's no reason for them to be. How do I stop this from happening?

Additionally, notice this happens with every color scheme I have installed and I'm using the `polyglot` plugin to provide with syntax highlighting rules for each language.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's highlighting SQL keywords. There is a setting in the PHP syntax highlighter to do that: `php_sql_query`.

This is off by default, so check your vimrc if you added that, or try adding `let g:php_sql_query = 1` to your vimrc.

Also see `:help ft-php-syntax`.